# Cannot connect to mysql server programmatically

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqljs

I am trying to connect to a mysql server with the [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) library. I used the following code:

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'mysql.panamath.org',
    user     : <username>,
    password : <password>,
    database : <database>
});

connection.connect(err => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log("Success connecting to database");
});
```

When I visit `mysql.panamath.org`, I am redirected to [here](https://east1-phpmyadmin.dreamhost.com/?hostname=mysql.panamath.org), where my credentials work fine. However, when I run this connection, I get this error:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user <username>@'129-2-181-10.wireless.umd.edu' (using password: YES)
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user <username>@'129-2-181-10.wireless.umd.edu' (using password: YES)",
  sqlState: '28000',
  fatal: true
```

It seems to be connecting to `'129-2-181-10.wireless.umd.edu'`. Interestingly, when I deployed through heroku, it was the same error except it was trying to connect to `'ec2-3-89-96-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com'`. I also tried to connect through the terminal:

```
$ mysql -h mysql.panamath.org -u <username> -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ...
```

with the same result.

What's going on here? Why can I connect through the website but not in my code? Is there another module or function for connecting to phpMyAdmin sites, or is the phpMyAdmin site connected to the server somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL cares about where you are connecting from.

Probably username@the-server-hosting-phpmyadmin is allowed to connect while username@129-2-181-10.wireless.umd.edu is not.

Consult the database administrator.